# Find & Replace RegEx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm having an text field where i need to find every keyword starting with a #hashtag (there can be multiple keywords) and replacing it with a link to an object already existent (If it exists).

So i have to do a `find` on the hashtag and if it exists replace it with a link.

`#goofy` should be replaced with `http://www.test.com/i/goofy` if it exists.

The RegEx: `/(?:\s|^)(?:#(?!(?:\d+|\w+?_|_\w+?)(?:\s|$)))(\w+)(?=\s|$)/i`.

What would be the best way to approach this ?

I'm stuck at how i replace every instance of keyword i find, with the link.

Comment: What about `#(\S+)`, http://regex101.com/r/vW2pQ7/9?

Comment: The regex works fine (WIP with exception handling on what exactly i dont want to include). I'm stuck at how to replace it.

Comment: I think you need to use gsub command..

Comment: Exactly, but somehow i fail at that :)

Comment: Example , `"foo bar #goofy".gsub(/#(\S+)/, '\1')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`String#gsub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-gsub):

```
re = /(?:\s|^)(?:#(?!(?:\d+|\w+?_|_\w+?)(?:\s|$)))(\w+)(?=\s|$)/i

"#goofy".gsub(re, 'http://www.test.com/i/\1')
#=> "http://www.test.com/i/goofy"
```

`\1` refers to the first capture group.

There seems to be a problem with your regular expression, though:

```
"123 #goofy".gsub(re, 'http://www.test.com/i/\1')
#=> "123http://www.test.com/i/goofy"
#       ^ no whitespace
```

Comment: Will finetune the regex. This should work fine with more than one instances right? It seems like putting the raw html in there breaks: gsub(re, <a href='test.com/i/\1'>#\1</a>) I'm sure im missing something fundamental :P

Comment: you're missing quotes: `gsub(re, '<a href="test.com/i/\1">#\1</a>')`